# Laravel - Update Uploaded Files in Input File

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, laravel, laravel-5

I want  to update my uploaded images, but as soon as I update 1 image the other images are removed why is that? I want to left them as what they are when they had been upload. help me please thanks.

[Here is an image of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f4mRr.png)

***Controller***

Update, public function, here is where I put the logic of the code

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
        'title' => 'required',
        'description' => 'required',
        'fleet_image.*' => 'image|nullable|max:1999'
    ]);
    $fleet = [];
    if ($request->has('fleet_image'))
    {   
        //Handle File Upload


        foreach ($request->file('fleet_image') as $key => $file)
        {
            // Get FileName
            $filenameWithExt = $file->getClientOriginalName();
            //Get just filename
            $filename = pathinfo( $filenameWithExt, PATHINFO_FILENAME);
            //Get just extension
            $extension = $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
            //Filename to Store
            $fileNameToStore = $filename.'_'.time().'.'.$extension;
            //Upload Image
            $path = $file->storeAs('public/fleet_images',$fileNameToStore);
            array_push($fleet, $fileNameToStore);
        }

        $fileNameToStore = serialize($fleet);
    }
    else
    {
        $fileNameToStore='noimage.jpg';
    }


    if (count($fleet)) {
        foreach ($fleet as $key => $value) {
        $fleetContent = Fleet::find($id);
        $fleetContent->title = $request->title[$key];
        $fleetContent->description = $request->description[$key];
        $implodedFleet = implode(' , ', $fleet);
        if($request->hasFile('fleet_image')){
       $fleetContent->fleet_image = $implodedFleet;
        }
       $fleetContent->save();
       return redirect('/admin/airlineplus/fleets')->with('success', 'Content Updated');
    }

}
return redirect('/admin/airlineplus/promotions')->with('success', 'Content Updated');


}
```

***View, edit.blade.php***

```
  {!! Form::open(['action'=>['Admin\FleetsController@update',$fleet->id], 'method' => 'POST','enctype'=>'multipart/form-data', 'name' => 'add_name', 'id' => 'add_name']) !!}

        <div class="table-responsive">
          <table class="table table-bordered" id="dynamic_field">
            <tr>
              <td>   {{Form::text('title[]', $fleet->title, ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Enter a Title', 'id'=>"exampleFormControlFile1"])}}<br>

                {{Form::textarea('description[]', $fleet->description, ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Enter a Description'])}} <br>
                <div class="card card-body col-md-8">

                @foreach(explode(' , ' ,$fleet->fleet_image) as $content)
                  <img src="{{ asset('storage/fleet_images/' . $content) }}" style="width:50px;height:50px;"><br/>

                  {{ Form::file('fleet_image[]',['id'=>'exampleFormControlFile1']) }}<br/>
                  @endforeach 
                </div>
             </td>

            </tr>
          </table>
          {{Form::hidden('_method', 'PUT')}}
          {{Form::submit('submit', ['class'=>'btn btn-primary', 'name'=>'submit'])}}
        </div>
    {!! Form::close() !!}
```

Answer (score 1):

**On your Controller**

```
$fleet = array();
$fleetContent = Fleet::find($id);
if ($request->has('fleet_image')) {
    for($i=0;$i<3;$i++){
        if(isset($request->file('fleet_image')[$i])){
            $filenameWithExt = $request->file('fleet_image')[$i]->getClientOriginalName();
            //Get just filename
            $filename = pathinfo( $filenameWithExt, PATHINFO_FILENAME);
            //Get just extension
            $extension = $request->file('fleet_image')[$i]->getClientOriginalExtension();
            //Filename to Store
            $fileNameToStore = $filename.'_'.time().'.'.$extension;
            //Upload Image
            $path = $request->file('fleet_image')[$i]->move('public/fleet_images',$fileNameToStore);
            array_push($fleet, $fileNameToStore);
        }else{
            $fleetContentExplode = explode(',',$fleetContent->fleet_image);
            array_push($fleet,$fleetContentExplode[$i]);
        }
    }
}
```

**On your View File**

```
{!! Form::open(['action'=>['Admin\FleetsController@update',$fleet->id], 'method' => 'POST','enctype'=>'multipart/form-data', 'name' => 'add_name', 'id' => 'add_name']) !!}

    <div class="table-responsive">
      <table class="table table-bordered" id="dynamic_field">
        <tr>
          <td>   {{Form::text('title', $fleet->title, ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Enter a Title', 'id'=>"exampleFormControlFile1"])}}<br>

            {{Form::textarea('description', $fleet->description, ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Enter a Description'])}} <br>
            <div class="card card-body col-md-8">

            @foreach(explode(' , ' ,$fleet->fleet_image) as $content)
              <img src="{{ asset('storage/fleet_images/' . $content) }}" style="width:50px;height:50px;"><br/>

              {{ Form::file('fleet_image[]',['id'=>'exampleFormControlFile1']) }}<br/>
              @endforeach 
            </div>
         </td>

        </tr>
      </table>
      {{Form::hidden('_method', 'PUT')}}
      {{Form::submit('submit', ['class'=>'btn btn-primary', 'name'=>'submit'])}}
    </div>
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

**NB::** I have just remove the array from your view input text

Comment: You are getting only 1 update for when you update something only first data can update then it's redirect for you putting your redirect() in foreach . I have just remove it from loop

Comment: no sir, when i remove the redirect an offset 1 error will occur

Comment: Trying to be used $file->move('public/fleet_images',$fileNameToStore); Instead of $path = $file->storeAs('public/fleet_images',$fileNameToStore); You can check your uploaded images not upload for this

Comment: I want to see your error . It's should work if you get your file name by pushing array_push()

Comment: actually, there is no error .. when I updated the images .. see the image above of my code.. there are 3 images there .. then if I update ONLY ONE image the other TWO will be removed automaticlly. that is my problem. I need the other two to stay and NOT REMOVED.

Comment: Dear That is happend for when you choose only 1 images and other input file are empty then $implodedFleet = implode(' , ', $fleet); line didn't get the other images name cause $fleet has only 1 array . You can solve this problem by checking others input field has data or not . Wait i am going to update my code

Comment: Dear , If i am not getting wrong , Your stored your fleet_image Field Value Like abc.jpg,def.jpg,ghi.jpg . I have updated my code depend on this field value . Please let me know if you are stored your value in a different way

Comment: Good thing, but what is ('photo') ? where did you get that name ? @ MD. Jubair Mizan

Comment: @ MD. Jubair Mizan , sir can you please tell me what is ('photo') and ('images') ? where did you get those names?

Comment: yes they are image file extensions all of them have file extensions

Comment: As i am trying it to my local server before updated my answer that's why i forgot to remove these thing . I have updated my code again . :)

Comment: I thought it was gonna work... Hi again, @MD. Jubair Mizan , the image was not inserting though it was also not removed i thought it was gonna work it was so close

Comment: I thought it would it was so close sir.. but it did not .. though the image was not removed.. but it was not changed either

Comment: It should work, can you please show me your controller ?

Comment: my controller is on above the code sir.. can you please edit it ? then ill marked it as answer if it worked

Comment: Dear Please check . I have updated your code. Please let me know if any issue

Comment: which code sir? mine or yours? it does not change my code :(

Comment: I have just updated my code once again . Let me know if it's doesn't work